# latest updates on .net framework for MC 70 symbol scanner

Tags: mobile, barcode-scanner, motorola

Where and how do I find the latest updates for .net framework on the MC 70 Motorola symbol scanner?  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the link here and it worked

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=65

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the ***[support page](https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Search?searchType=simple&searchTerm=1)***?